# React native Android ScrollView scrollTo not working

Tags: scrollview, react-native

I am trying to use a **horizontal ScrollView in React Native** for Android, where the starting position is in the middle of the scrolling images rather than (0,0).

The `scrollTo` method seems to be called correctly inside `componentDidMount` but nothing moves in the application, it still shows as starting the scroll all the way to the left.

Since this is Android I don't have access to contentOffset props or I would set that directly, according to the documentation.  Here is the code:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Component,
} = React;
var precomputeStyle = require('precomputeStyle');

class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    //this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myScroll.scrollTo(100);
    console.log("called DidMount");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView ref={(ref) => this.myScroll = ref}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          bounces={true}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onAnimationEnd}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onAnimationEnd(e) {
    console.log("curr offset: " + e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  page: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

module.exports = Carousel;
```

Comment: Can you try adding a Y coordinate as well? E.g. `scrollTo(100, 0)`.

Comment: I did and the problem stays the same, the missing coordinate just defaults to zero if not specified.

Comment: I think it's actually `scrollTo(y, x)` but that syntax is deprecated. It's now `scrollTo({x: n, y: n, animated: bool})` and as Rob mentioned these are you can omit `x`, `y` and `animated` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same issue, and wasted several hours no it:

- 1: in android, ScrollView can scroll only when its size < content's size
- 2: in react native android, if you call ScrollView.scrollTo() in componentDidMount, it won't work, because ScrollView has a layout animation when create, you can find it in ReactScrollView.java

```js
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // Call with the present values in order to re-layout if necessary
    scrollTo(getScrollX(), getScrollY());
}
```

so, you must delay it after the animation

```js
componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.myScroll.scrollTo(100);
        console.log("called DidMount");
    })  
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but I had to add a delay inside this function: `_.delay(() => this._scroll.scrollTo({x: 1000, animated: false}), 100);`

Comment: Just using a delay without the interaction manager worked for me on a ScrollView. I'll post an answer with the code as I had trouble finding a good resource on this.

Comment: Thank you, InteractionManager did the job for me

Answer (score 32):

I wanted to avoid using delays and timers so after a bit of digging I found that using `onLayout` works very smooth:

```
scrollToInitialPosition = () => {
  this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 100 });
}
...
<ScrollView
  ref={(ref) => { this.scrollViewRef = ref; }}
  onLayout={this.scrollToInitialPosition}
/>
```

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer, notice that the answer selected as best is from year 2016.

Comment: This worked for me! I struggled for quite some time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks dude ! This should be the accepted answer. Saved my time :)

Comment: Legendary stuff

Answer (score 25):

This works on React Native 0.44.0. Thanks for the hint @Eldelshell. It also seems to work with any timeout value. At least on the emulator. I found that the answer involving `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` did nothing to fix the issue but perhaps that's a difference in versions.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this._scroll.scrollTo({y: 100})
  }, 1)
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the ScrollView's initial animation is finished within 1ms. This may happen most of the time, but it's not guaranteed. That's why `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions()` is the preferred solution, and `setTimeout()` is somewhat sloppy.

Comment: @NathanK You didn't read Phil's answer. He clearly stated that using `InteractionManager` did not fix the problem for him. It didn't fix the problem for me either. The only solution I can find that fixes this issue is to use `setTimeout` with a low value.

Comment: Same for me it's not working with `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` but working with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a more modern, hooks version of this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {

 const componentRef = useRef(null)

 // this is the same as useEffect but only runs after finishing rendering
  useLayoutEffect(() => {

    // unlike class examples, the actual ref is stored in the current property
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 100 })

    // this empty because we don't care about any other variables, 
    // if you add other stuff into this function, 
    // you'll have to add any hook based variables into this array
  }, [])

 // ditto about current here:
 return (
   <ScrollView ref={(ref) => (componentRef.current = ref)}>
    {...}
   </ScrollView>)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [listIndex, setListIndex] = useState(inqId?list.findIndex(obj => 
obj.InqID == inqId):null);
const [ref, setRef] = useState(null)
scrollToPosition = () => {
  listRef.scrollTo({ y: 50*ref });
}

<ScrollView
  ref={(ref) => { setRef(ref) }}
  onLayout={scrollToPosition}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @David Nathan, using `InteractionManager` works for me.
also note that unlike `setTimeout` , `runAfterInteractions` will not delay active animations.

From [InteractionManager docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager)