# How to make React-Native "scrollTo" behave identically on Android than on iOS when ScrollView is small

Tags: react-native

Consider [this simple ScrollView](https://snack.expo.io/H1AeNGx4W).

- On iOS, clicking on the text will but the text to the top because `scrollTo({ y: 250 })` scrolls even if end of scrollView is reached.
- On Android, the text doesn't move.

How to get on Android the same behavior we have on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around this by adding padding to the `contentContainerStyle` of the `ScrollView`. A good starting point would be to add padding equal to the height of the device's screen.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const ANDROID_SCREEN_HEIGHT_PADDING = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

then, when rendering:

```
<ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: ANDROID_SCREEN_HEIGHT_PADDING}}>
...
</ScrollView>
```

You could use this for necessary extra Android padding in every direction. If you are using `horizontal={true}`, for example, you could add padding equal to the width of the screen and add it to the `paddingLeft` style property to get the intended scrolling behavior on Android.

This behavior is due to the underlying implementation of `ScrollView` on Android in React-Native. See also:
[React native Android ScrollView scrollTo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208477/react-native-android-scrollview-scrollto-not-working)