# React Native ScrollView scrollTo function is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make scroll to the top, if a certain condition is met, in the component's `componentWillReceiveProps` event ... but nothing happens:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     // some code...

    if (newQuery === query && this.scrollViewRef.current) {
      console.log('Should scroll to top'); // << logs successfully

      this.scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        duration: 500,
        animated: true,
      });
    }
  }
```

Code snippet of how I created ref for the scrollView:

```
class SearchResult extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.scrollViewRef = React.createRef();
  }
//...
}
```

render method:

```
render () {
   return (
      <ScrollView
        ref={this.scrollViewRef}
        contentContainerStyle={{ marginVertical: 8 }}
      >
    ...
    )
}
```

I also tried to scroll manually via a button press ... doesn't work as well

Any help ?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: nothing at all ... I logged `this.scrollViewRef.current`, and scrollTo function was there

Comment: Have you tried `this.scrollViewRef.getNode().scrollTo()`?

Comment: unfortunately, it gave this error: 
`this.scrollVieeRef.getNode is not a function` ...

Comment: Yeah can you show how you do the ref?

Comment: exactly like in the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Comment: definitely ... check out the edit please...

Comment: Try doing the ref the other way: `ref={(_) => this.ref = _}` and then try the `.getNode()` as above.

Comment: @Colin thank you very much indeed ... tried the second format of making a ref ... but went again to the 'silence mode' ... no warning ... errors ... as if I did nothing

Comment: @Colin ... check out my answer ... the issue was in the container ... thank you for all of your suggestions anyway

Comment: Ah interesting, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out ...

The `scrollView` worked perfectly in an isolated env ( a brand new project ) ...

I thought the issue could be in the container of that scrollview ... and I found that the parent component has also a `ScrollView` ... once i removed it, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

For those people who use `useRef()` method and gets `'xRef.scrollTo' is not a function` error, try to use it like `xRef.current.scrollTo({[YOUR_PARAMS]})`.

I didn't know this `current` thing and was getting crazy.

Answer (score 0):

React Native docs say:

*Note: The weird function signature is due to the fact that, for historical reasons, the function also accepts separate arguments as an alternative to the options object. This is deprecated due to ambiguity (y before x), and SHOULD NOT BE USED.*

Maybe try `scrollToOffset` method, if you are also using FlatList with ScrollView?

Comment: Thank you but this is a warning not to use old signature of scrollTo (x, y, animation) ... we should use scollTo({ x: 5, y: 5, animated: true }) ... and that's what im currently using.... and the code in my question doesn't throw any error or even a warning

Comment: I see. Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208477/react-native-android-scrollview-scrollto-not-working) to see if this is similar??

Comment: yes I did my own research before posting ... and I came across this stackoverflow post ... tried everything in it ... didn't work as well ... but thank u anyway