# ScrollToLocation not working on initial mount

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-sectionlist

I'd like to add a SectionList to my app such that it renders to a specific section (that isn't the first section in the list). Calling scrollToLocation on componentDidMount does not work; however, adding a button that calls scrollToLocation does. Is there a reason for this?

Could this be due to the SectionList reference (I've tried a few approaches for assigning reference, e.g. variable assignment, function assignment, using createRef, etc.)?

Here is a link to a stripped-down Expo snack to illustrate what I mean: https://snack.expo.io/@bobbymoogs/scrolltolocation-on-componentdidmount.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310445/187482) is to use `onLayout` to trigger the scroll:

```js
scrollToInitialPosition = () => {
  this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 100 });
}
...
<ScrollView
  ref={(ref) => { this.scrollViewRef = ref; }}
  onLayout={this.scrollToInitialPosition}
/>
```

Note there are lots of other suggestions using `setTimeout`, `componentDidUpdate`, `InteractionManager`, etc. However using onLayout was the only one that worked for me (and also seems to me to be the cleanest).